# what will happen if enableAsyncPostRender is set true in slickgrid?

Tags: angularjs, slickgrid

Why do we use the enableAsyncPostRender in Slickgrid, if enableAsyncPostRender is set to true what will be the change happening in the Slickgrid.

Answer (score 0):

If **enableAsyncPostRender** is set to true, any columns with **asyncPostRender** property will be process based on your set delay (**asyncPostRenderDelay**). This is very useful if you are working with a very complex cell rendition (e.g. sparkline) so it will not affect the speed and responsiveness of your table. If you don't specify 
**asyncPostRender** in any of the columns,  nothing is really changed to SlickGrid. Alternatively, you can also add **setTimeout** inside your formatter.

An example is available here https://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example10-async-post-render.html

Comment: I've also added a postrender async cleanup in my repo https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid (scroll down for readme). This is to prevent memory leaks when the postrendered content requires explicit cleanup. Lots of other fixes and features there too.